# cannot add version to item null exception when adding contact to a list

Tags: sxa, list-manager

I am trying to create a list using a CSV file, but somehow, I cannot do so because of the underlying issue.

I understand that he is trying to create an item and a version, why does it fail?
How can I fix this?

```
12340 13:39:22 ERROR Failed to add the item version. Item ID: {85F59B23-CE92-4ABC-8D34-B3E4B24D5DAC}, database: master, language: nl-NL
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: De objectverwijzing is niet op een exemplaar van een object ingesteld.
Source: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite
   bij Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Services.PushCloneService.AddVersion(Item item)
   bij Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Services.PushCloneHandlerService.DataEngineOnAddedVersion(Object sender, ExecutedEventArgs`1 executedEventArgs)
   bij System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   bij Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   bij Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.AddVersionCommand.Executed()
   bij Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   bij Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.AddVersion(Item item)

12340 13:39:22 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP POST
URL http://www-911.sitecore.sc/sitecore/api/ssc/ListManagement/Import/{F43A3597-703E-4016-B44C-65F590E09D46}/ImportContactsFromMediaLibraryAndCreateList

Exception System.NullReferenceException: De objectverwijzing is niet op een exemplaar van een object ingesteld.
   bij Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Services.PushCloneService.AddVersion(Item item)
   bij Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Services.PushCloneHandlerService.DataEngineOnAddedVersion(Object sender, ExecutedEventArgs`1 executedEventArgs)
   bij System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   bij Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   bij Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.AddVersionCommand.Executed()
   bij Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   bij Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.AddVersion(Item item)
   bij Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.AddVersion(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   bij Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.AddFromTemplateCommand.‭‮‮⁫⁭⁫‌‬‭‮‏‎⁪‍⁭‭‮⁪‎‫‏‭⁪‮⁫⁫⁯‬⁬⁭‌⁬‮⁯⁯⁮‮‫⁪‫‮(String , Item , ID , ID )
   bij Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.AddFromTemplateCommand.DoExecute()
   bij Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.AddFromTemplateCommand.DoExecute()
   bij Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   bij Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.AddFromTemplate(String itemName, ID templateId, Item destination, ID newId)
   bij Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.AddFromTemplate(String itemName, ID templateId, Item destination, ID newItemId)
   bij Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.AddFromTemplate(String itemName, ID templateId, Item destination, ID newItemId)
   bij Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Repository.ItemDefinitionRepositoryBase`1.CreateItem(Guid definitionId, String definitionAlias, Guid templateId, Item parentItem)
   bij Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Repository.ItemDefinitionRepositoryBase`1.CreateItem(TDefinitionRecord definition, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
   bij Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Repository.ItemDefinitionRepositoryBase`1.Save(TDefinitionRecord definition, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
   bij Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`2.Save(TDefinition definition, Boolean activate)
   bij Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`2.SaveAsync(TDefinition definition, Boolean activate)
   bij Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.ContactListRepository.Update(ContactListModel entity)
   bij Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.ImportController.UpdateContactListSubscriptions(Guid listId, SubscriptionViewModel importSubscriptionDefinition)
   bij Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.ImportController.ImportContacts(Guid listId, IDictionary`2 mapping, String mediaItemId)
   bij Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.ImportController.ImportContactsFromMediaLibraryAndCreateList(Dictionary`2 mapping, String id)
   bij lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   bij System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   bij System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- Einde van stacktracering vanaf vorige locatie waar uitzondering is opgetreden ---
   bij System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bij System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bij System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
12340 13:39:22 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP POST
URL http://www-911.sitecore.sc/sitecore/api/ssc/ListManagement/Import/{F43A3597-703E-4016-B44C-65F590E09D46}/ImportContactsFromMediaLibraryAndCreateList
```

When I look for the item ID   {85F59B23-CE92-4ABC-8D34-B3E4B24D5DAC} in Sitecore, I can find the corresponding item and it has a version. So I am a little bit confused

[image]

Comment: As per the message, try enabling debug compilation by setting debug=true in the instance webroot's web.config found at the root like below : 
`<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1">`

Comment: you should revert back to debug="false" later after debugging this issue.. as mentioned in the comments section near the compilation tag

Comment: @PaulsonMaclean Thanks for the tips, I will try it out and will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few options to solve the problem.

**1. Via support** [recommended]

Please contact Sitecore support. They will provide you with proper hotfix for this issue.

Issue is caused by missing null check and I am pretty sure that there is a fix for it already.

**2. Fix problem on your on own**

- Create your own implementation of **PushCloneService**
- Fix problem (overwrite `AddVersion` method)
- Overwrite default service implementation with yours:
  `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Services.PushCloneService, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite`

**3. Brute force** - fast [not recommended]

Not recommended solution but this can quickly unblock your work.

Remove this processor

```
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Pipelines.InitializeManagers.InitializePushCloneManager, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite" />
```

If you do it some of the features might not work correctly (delegated areas)